# if else condition not working as expected in python's scipy code

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I'm defining a function for solving my differential equations in scipy's solve_ivp.

```
def conv(t,Z):
    global sw,von,X

    if  X[1]>=von or X[0]>0:
            zdot=LA.inv(v1).dot(A1).dot(v1).dot(Z).reshape(4,1)+LA.inv(v1).dot(B1).dot(U)

            von=0.7
            X=v1.dot(Z)
    else:
            zdot= LA.inv(v0).dot(A0).dot(v0).dot(Z).reshape(4,1)+LA.inv(v0).dot(B0).dot(U)

            X=v0.dot(Z)
    return np.squeeze(np.asarray(zdot))
```

and solving my equation using

```
sw=0
e1,v1=LA.eig(A1)
von=0
Z= np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
X=v1.dot(Z)
U = np.array([[vin], [vdon]])
Z0= np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
V=v1
sol = solve_ivp(conv, tspan,Z0,method='Radau')
```

Initially as `sw`=`0` and `X` =`[0,0,0,0]` , I expect the `if` condition  to be satisfied and the `if block` to be implemented. But the program is executing the else block.I'm not able to understand the problem.

Comment: The operator precedence makes your boolean expression equivalent to `sw==0 and (X[1]>=von or (sw==1 and X[0]>0))`. Is that what you want

Comment: Yes, I want it like this only.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you discussed in math.SE or scicomp.SE the mathematical side of the problem you want to solve and how to build an algorithm around it. What is actually the state variable where you expect a continuous solution? The basis switch will make here `X` discontinuous, while the "decoupled" `Z` is continuous over the phase changes. As the order in the eigen-decomposition is not "natural", it is a design choice and could be random, there is no intrinsic reason why `Z` should be continuous.

Comment: But technically for the very first condition, the `if` condition should get implemented. All the state variables are expected to just switch once i.e at the last time step. I don't have access to math.SE

Comment: @LutzLehmann ,my question has been removed I suppose.the euler code is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61501213/equivalent-of-euler-using-solve-ivp-in-python?noredirect=1#comment108792272_61501213

Answer (score 0):

According to Python Zen N2 "Explicit is better than implicit"

```py
def conv(t,Z):
    global sw,von,X

    if sw==0 and (X[1]>=von or (sw==1 and X[0]>0)):
            zdot=LA.inv(v1).dot(A1).dot(v1).dot(Z).reshape(4,1)+LA.inv(v1).dot(B1).dot(U)
            sw=1
            von=0.7
            X=v1.dot(Z)
    else:
            zdot= LA.inv(v0).dot(A0).dot(v0).dot(Z).reshape(4,1)+LA.inv(v0).dot(B0).dot(U)
            sw=0
            X=v0.dot(Z)
    return np.squeeze(np.asarray(zdot))
```

Then debugger is the best way to find why you have True or (False and (False))
I may see from the values you have already provided that

- `(sw==1 and X[0]>0)` is equal to False because `X[0]=0` in your initial condition
- You have not mentioned what is the value of `von` in the `(X[1]>=von)`

But based on results you get `von` is greater than 0. Check that and make explicit comparisons in the code. This will help a lot in the future.

Comment: I've edited the question .von=0 only.This code is still returning wrong results

Comment: Have you tried to debug? I am using pcharm and by putting breakpoint to the if statement line I can check the state of all the variables inspecting their values. That helps a lot. 
It looks like X contains something that is not zero.
In case you are not familiar enough with debugging, just add a line 

print(sw,X[1],von ,sw, X[0]) 

before the if statement.
That is dirty trick but may give fast help.